# How i can purchase same product again In app purchase in react native (react-native-iap 7.5.0) for android?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, react-native-iap

I was using react native iap version 4.4.3 and currently i have upgrade my react native version 0.66 and react native iap version 7.53.

`consumeAllItemsAndroid` method was worked for purchase same product again in the android but now this method has been deprecated and alternate method is `flushFailedPurchasesCachedAsPendingAndroid` which is not Consume all items so we are able to buy same product again.

**As per the iap change log 7.2.0**

**flushFailedPurchasesCachedAsPendingAndroid**:-
Consume all 'ghost' purchases (that is, pending payment that already failed but is still marked as pending in Play Store cache). Android only.
for more information please check this [link](https://github.com/dooboolab/react-native-iap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#720)

So how would I able to purchase same product again in android?